# Why does std::string store content at the same address inside a loop?

Tags: c++, char, std, stdstring

I need to create a char[] dynamically. I would like to use std::string instead of working on char[] directly since I don't need to take care of the memory management with std::string. Here is my example code:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<char*> char_vec;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        std::string s;
        s = "test" + std::to_string(i);
        char_vec.push_back(const_cast<char*>(s.c_str()));
    }

    for(auto& ele : char_vec)
    {
        std::cout << ele << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The output is:
[image], which is not what I want.

In my understanding, the string s created inside the loop should be completely new in every iteration, but in fact, all strings use the same address to store the content. Why does this happen? How should I modify my code to achieve my target?

Thank you for all the help!

---

Update on 2023-01-10:

I tried the following code based on the answers:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<char*> char_vec;
    std::vector<std::string> str_vec;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        // str_vec.emplace_back("test" + std::to_string(i));
        str_vec.push_back("test" + std::to_string(i));
        char_vec.push_back(const_cast<char*>(str_vec.back().c_str()));
    }

    for(auto& ele : char_vec)
    {
        std::cout << ele << std::endl;
    }
}
```

but still can't output the desired results. Can I ask why this doesn't work?

Comment: Each `std::string` created in the loop happens to be instantiated at exactly the same spot in memory. Note that the C strings you store are gone after the for loop when `s` goes out of scope. The program therefore has undefined behavior.

Comment: On every iteration through the loop, a temporary `std::string` variable is created. Then you take a pointer to the data that variable manages, and place it into the vector. Then the variable is destroyed, and so is the data it managed. At the end, you have a vector stuffed full of dangling pointers. Attempting to use these pointers afterwards exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Because (probably) SSO

Comment: @PaulSanders Yes - and that probably saved OP from a world of hurt later. If longer strings had been created, OP would probably have thought that all's well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Storing the `s.c_str()` pointers in the vector, when the `s` lives only until the end of the loop iteration, will cause undefined behavior, at latest when you try to read through these pointers.

It is immaterial whether the pointers have the same value. As soon as the scope of `s` ends, they become invalid. The memory they address can then be reused for whatever by the compiler/library. You are not guaranteed to be able to read anything sensible from them at all. That you got even `test9` back was "luck".

You should be using a `std::vector<std::string>` and then just `char_vec.push_back(s);` (or if you want to optimize `char_vec.push_back(std::move(s))`, but only because you do not use `s` after the `push_back`).

Comment: Or better still `char_vec.push_back(std::move(s));`

Comment: @user17732522 I have updated the code based on your suggestion but still can't get the desired outputs. Can I ask why?

Comment: @john can I ask why std::move() is better?

Comment: Because it saves the cost of copying the string. Since you are no longer using the variable `s` the memory it is referencing can just be 'moved' into the vector, without having to allocate new memory and copy the characters over.

Comment: @ChuanXu `std::vector` stores its elements contiguously. If you add a new element and the reserved memory block becomes too small, then `std::vector` has to make a new (larger) allocation and copy/move the old elements over into it. This invalidates any pointer you obtained into the `std::string`s. If you need to rely on the `char*` pointers remaining valid as long as the vector is valid, then you either must call `.reserve(10)` on the vector first and make sure to never increase its size beyond `10` or you need to use a different container, e.g. `std::list`.

Comment: @ChuanXu Or better, form the vector of `char*` only after you are done modifying the `std::string` vector. Even better, try to avoid having to form an array of `char*` pointers like that in the first place. Normally you don't need that in modern C++. But if you need it (e.g. because you have to call a C API), then scope the vector of `char*` as narrowly as possible.

Comment: @user17732522 Cool, your explanation totally makes sense. Thank you.